# Deadletters encountered when communicating between spark clusters with akka actor

Tags: scala, apache-spark, akka

Since spark is built on top of Akka, I want to use Akka to send and receive messages between spark clusters.

According to this tutorial, https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/spark-activator/blob/master/src/main/scala/StreamingApp.scala, I can run StreamingApp locally and send messages to the actorStream itself.

Then I tried to attach the sender part to my another spark master and send message from spark master to the remote actor in StreamingApp. The code is as follows

```
object SenderApp extends Serializable {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val driverPort = 12345
        val driverHost = "xxxx"
        val conf = new SparkConf(false) 
            .setMaster("spark://localhost:8888") // Connecting to my spark master
            .setAppName("Spark Akka Streaming Sender")
            .set("spark.logConf", "true")
            .set("spark.akka.logLifecycleEvents", "true")
        val actorName = "helloer"

        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

        val actorSystem = SparkEnv.get.actorSystem

        val url = s"akka.tcp://sparkDriver@$driverHost:$driverPort/user/Supervisor0/$actorName"

        val helloer = actorSystem.actorSelection(url)

        helloer ! "Hello"
        helloer ! "from"
        helloer ! "Spark Streaming"
        helloer ! "with"
        helloer ! "Scala"
        helloer ! "and"
        helloer ! "Akka"
    }
}
```

Then I got messages from StreamingApp saying it encountered DeadLetters.
The detailed messages are:

```
INFO LocalActorRef: Message [akka.remote.transport.AssociationHandle$Disassociated] from Actor[akka://sparkDriver/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://sparkDriver/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FsparkDriver%40111.22.33.444%3A56840-4#-2094758237] was not delivered. [5] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this article:
http://typesafe.com/activator/template/spark-streaming-scala-akka

I changed the helloer, it works now

```
val timeout = 100 seconds

val helloer = Await.result(actorSystem.actorSelection(url).resolveOne(timeout), 
                           timeout)
```